# Firebase connection limit reached

Tags: python, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was working with Pyrebase( python library for firebase) and was trying .stream() method but when I saw my firebase dashboard it showed 100 connection limit reached. Is there any way to remove those concurrent connection?

Comment: concurrent connection means the number of clients connected to dabase, there is no way bypass that so you have two options downscale your system to have less clients... or pay for more

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 100 concurrent connections to the database for Firebase projects that are on the free Spark plan. To raise the limit, upgrade your project to a paid plan.

Comment: I don't want to upgrade as a college project I was just playing around with pyrebase .So is there any way to remove those connections?